# How to pass category ID to form post

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I just `re-structured my database` to have a `category` table instead of using a category column on my main form. How can I pass the `category_id` to my form so my form POSTs properly? Right now i'm getting this error, and I believe it's because my `category_id` is type integer and i'm submitting a string.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Also I manually inserted `Comp Time Used`, `OT Accrued`, `Sick Time` and `Vacation Time Used` Into my `category` table via PHPMYADMIN. Is there a better way to do this? Like maybe inside my Model?

I have a **form** that looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="categoryForm">Category:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="categoryForm" placeholder="Category">
      <option name="category_id">Comp Time Used</option>
      <option name="category_id">OT Accrued</option>
      <option name="category_id">Sick Time</option>
      <option name="category_id">Vacation Time Used</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My **migration** for my form looks like:

```
Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->date('start_day');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->time('start_time');
    $table->time('finish_time');
    $table->time('duration');
    $table->text('notes');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

});
```

My **migration** for my categories table:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('type');
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have fake data to display on your drop down or you just want to insert data into your `db` from a form?

Comment: The problem is not with `category_id`, it is with `start_date`, which you are passing an integer instead of a datetime. Also, you don't have to add `name="category_id"` on every option, just add it to the select...

Comment: I have posted an answer, the property of `name` does not go with `<option>`, always use `value` if you want your backend to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want to pass an array from a controller to your form on your blade view in laravel.

Your Controller method should be something like this.

```
use App\Category; //import model
public function create()
{
   $categories = Category::all();
   return view('folder.bladefile', compact('categories')); //by this you will be able to access categories in your bladefile.
}
```

Inside of your blade file, you can do something like this

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="categoryForm" placeholder="Category">
   @foreach($categories as $category)
     <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
   @endforeach;
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `category_id`, it is with `start_date`, which you are passing an integer instead of a datetime, as it says the error.

Also, it is not correct to add `name="category_id"` on every option, you have to add it to the select.

On your `<option>` you have to set a value for each option. For instance: `<option value="1">Comp Time Used</option>`. That way, you will be able to retrieve the correct category_id with `request('category_id')`.